# Adding an item in index.html page to favourite page with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I have a recipe app already fetched from an API to my index.html. I added a favourite icon on each of the recipe fetched. *When I click on the favourite icon I want a JavaScript function that will store the recipe image, title and URL as an array on my local storage then display it on my favourite.html as an inner html.*

Anyone to help me go about this? Its really challenging to me at the moment.

I tried storing on my local storage when favourite icon is clicked and displaying on favourite.html page.

I expected to get the image, title/label and URL saved as an array to my local storage and displayed as an inner html on my favourite.html page.

But my code is only saving the title/label of each recipe when the favourite icon is clicked on local storage. Then for my favourite.html nothing is displaying.

Below is the js code I did:

```
 function addToFavourites(recipeLabel) {
      const favourites = getFromLocalStorage(favListKey) || [];
      if (!favourites.includes(recipeLabel)) {
          favourites.push(recipeLabel);
          saveToLocalStorage(favListKey, favourites);
          alert(${recipeLabel} added to favourites!);
                   } else {
          alert(${recipeLabel} is already in your favuorites!);
      }  }
   function saveToLocalStorage(key, value) {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }
```

Comment: Without seeing your code I can only summise, 

You're likely storing the title/label in an array external to the original array, but when you navigate to favourite.html you're not requesting the information from the stored information. Can you post some sample code? and we can help direct you accordingly?

Comment: okay @BaneStar007 below is the js code i did

`function addToFavourites(recipeLabel) {

    const favourites = getFromLocalStorage(favListKey) || [];

    if (!favourites.includes(recipeLabel)) {

        favourites.push(recipeLabel);

        saveToLocalStorage(favListKey, favourites);

        alert(`${recipeLabel} added to favourites!`);

            
    } else {

        alert(`${recipeLabel} is already in your favuorites!`);

    }

}


function saveToLocalStorage(key, value) {

    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));

} `

Comment: Please don't post extended code in comments. Edit the question, and include a proper [mre] of your issue directly in there.

Comment: Can you please add the favourite.html code too in your post?

Comment: Ok cool, I assume that code is in your index.html, 

So what about the code in favourite.html?

Can you edit your question to include the JS from that file too?